# Why can't I define the upper range of my code with a variable? - Numerical Integration Method

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python, so my code is very simple.
I have a project to write code which approximates integrals using the rectangle rule, followed by the trapezium rule:

```
    a = float(input('Lower limit ---> '))

while True:
    b = float(input('Upper limit ---> '))

    if b > a:
        break
    elif a == b:
        print('Integral = 0.')
    else:
        print('Invalid input.')

N = float(input('Number of integral divisions ---> '))

h = float((b - a) / N)

print('For the integral in the range {} to {} with {} divisions, the step size is {}.'.format(a,b,N,h))


def f(x):
    return(np.exp(-x) * sin(x))

summation = (f(a) + f(b))

for points in range(a, N - 1):
    summation = summation + f(a + (points * h))

I = h * summation

print(I)
```

Near the end, I try to use a for loop from the initial limit to minus 1 the number of step sizes.
I've defined this as a float but it I keep getting the error

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `range` expects integer arguments, but you give it floating-point values. Either use `int`, not `float`, for `a` and `N`, or use something like `arange` or `linspace` from the NumPy package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you collect your `a` and `N` variables, you convert them in `float`:

```
a = float(input('Lower limit ---> '))
N = float(input('Number of integral divisions ---> '))
```

Then you try to iterate from a to N, but let's assume `a=0.42` and `n=3.14`.
How do you expect python to behave?

```
print([x for x in range(0.42,3.14)]) # Raise TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as a
```

so you have to convert your float into integers (`a = int(a), N = int(N)`):

```
print([x for x in range(0,3)]) # prints [0, 1, 2]
```

or you can use numpy, and define 2 float values and the step between them:

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])
```

Comment: you are even already working with numpy, so the latest solution should be the best to implement

Answer (score 0):

`a`, `b` and `N` are floats. `range` does not allow its arguments to be floats so you will need to convert them to `int`:

`for points in range(int(a), int(N - 1)):`

Comment: Since the OP is using numpy, they could do `np.arange`

Comment: The OP has `np.exp(-x)` in the `f` function, which gives me the assumption `numpy` is being used in some form

Comment: Apologies, I import numpy and some things from math earlier in the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly states that you are using floats where an integer is wanted.

Read the documentation of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) - what lead you to believe is is capable of doing anything with floats?

There are unlimited floats between 1 and 2 - and still *very many* if you take the resolution of float into consideration - how should python be able to give you all of them as range?

Comment: Nothing led me to believe it could. It was a complete lack of understanding of what Python IS capable of that led me to assume it could. Thanks for the help.